# Windows 8 App - container for html pages

Tags: security, hyperlink, winjs, temporary-files

I would like to create windows 8 mobile app to be a container for other web apps. I mean this app would download from my server packs of HTML, CSS & Javascript, save it to database and user could open these downloaded apps. It works for Android and iOS, but for Win8 not.

Downloading and saving to database works. In order to open downloaded app I create temporary folder, save all files there and create link

```
<a href="file://path_to_index.html">Open</a>
```

But link not opening. I guess Windows security policy doesn't allow to open local links in mobile apps.

Do you have any solution to this or any idea to alternative approach?

EDIT:

I tried write files to local storage and open it in ms-webview according to jakerella, but it not working. Function webview.navigate('ms-appdata:///local/index.html') throws exception: wrong argument

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#my_button').click(function () {
        var HTML_CONTENT = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title></title> </head> <body> <button id="btn">Click me!</button> <div id="content"></div> <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script> </body> </html>';
        var JS_CONTENT = 'document.getElementById("btn").onclick=function(){var a=document.getElementById("content");a.innerHTML="Clicked!"};';

        var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;
        localFolder.createFileAsync("index.html", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).then(function (file) {
            Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file, HTML_CONTENT).then(function() {
                localFolder.createFileAsync("index.js", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).then(function (file2) {
                    Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file2, JS_CONTENT).then(function () {
                        try {
                            var wv = $('#wv')[0];
                            wv.navigate('ms-appdata:///local/index.html');
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.log(e.message);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App1</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <!-- App1 references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="my_button">Open page</button>
    <x-ms-webview id="wv">

    </x-ms-webview>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT2:

OK, it works! I found solution here: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/10/01/blending-apps-and-sites-with-the-html-x-ms-webview.aspx

Comment: Well, it depends how you want to "open" the downloaded file... This [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781229.aspx) talks about loading local resources, but the same idea can be applied to links, which is that you use the `ms-appx` or `ms-appx-web` protocols. What do you want to happen when the user clicks on the link?

Comment: When I click on the link I want the page to be opened

Comment: Uh huh... where? How? External browser? In a `ms-webview`? There are lots of ways to load an html file.

Comment: ms-webview is ok. I want to write files (html, css, js) to local folder and later open index.html from this folder in ms-webview. But what is full address of index.html which I must provide to ms-webview?

Comment: If you save the html file to the [local data location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465118.aspx) then you would use `ms-appdata:///local/path_to_index.html`

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have two approaches.

One of the is using `x-ms-webview` which is what you found.
The other would be setting the html straight into an element by code using the [execUnsafeLocalFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767331.aspx) which is strongly not recommended by MS, but I guess you could make a responsible use out of it.

Comment: Using execUnsafeLocationFunction is there to give you a chance to ask whether you really trust the source of the code. If it's something you're generating yourself, then it's just fine. If you're downloading from some arbitrary place on the web, on the other hand, probably not--then you should use a Webview or other container.